# Handling function errors

Tags: swift

I don't understand from the documentation how to do the error handling, I have the following:

```
func myFunc() async -> TransactionsClassAModel {
    let url = URL(string: "..."))
    
    let undecodedData = try! await networkingTools.afRequest(url: url!)
    let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionsClassAModel.self, from: undecodedData)
    
    return decodedData
}
```

I tried something like:

```
do {
    let undecodedData = try await networkingTools.afRequest(url: url!)
    try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionsClassAModel.self, from: undecodedData)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

and the return statement says `Cannot find 'decodedData' in scope` and a warning: `Result of call to 'decode(_:from:)' is unused`

Can someone explain me how this works please.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, don’t do `try!` which means you will crash if an error is thrown.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes that's what I'm trying to avoid, crashing the app. I want to cover as many possible catch so I can handle it, but don't know how to pass that to the return

Comment: Then why are you using it in every example? Why not make the function throwing?

Comment: Because I didn't know, I'll edit the sample above. I left the 1st code with it since it's what I have and what's wrong. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: For starters, read this: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html
Then decide what you want to do in case of error: crash, assign nil to a variable, throw error to the caller, or nothing at all (just log it for example). Depending on that, you need to do `try!`, `try?` or `try`. Then depending on that choice you can decide what to do with the variables.

Comment: @KirilS. that's the docs I was reading, I just want to log it for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix is creating one `do` block, from which you return if everything is fine. And one catch block which will happen if anything is going wrong. You also have to adjust your function signature to return optional value, since in the case of failure you probably won't have a `TransactionsClassAModel`:

```
func myFunc() async -> TransactionsClassAModel? {

    let url = URL(string: "...")

    do {

        let undecodedData = try await networkingTools.afRequest(url: url!)
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionsClassAModel.self, from: undecodedData)
        /* do anything you need */
        return decodedData // success
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil // no object in this case
    }
}
```

you can also separate blocks, so each try is in its own block, e.g.:

```
func myFunc() async -> TransactionsClassAModel? {

    let url = URL(string: "...")

    var undecodedData: Data // or optional Data? if function can return nil
    do {
        let undecodedData = try await networkingTools.afRequest(url: url!)
    } catch {
        print("Failed in afReqest: \(error)")
        return nil
    }

    var decodedData: TransactionClassModel?
    do {
        decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionsClassAModel.self, from: undecodedData)
    } catch {
        print("Failed in decode: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
    return decodedData
}
```

You can also separate data decoding into private function, and return on that function call:

```
private func decodeMyData(_ undecodedData; Data) -> TransactionsClassAModel? {
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionsClassAModel.self, from: undecodedData)
    } catch {
        print("Failed in decode: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

func myFunc() async -> TransactionsClassAModel? {

    let url = URL(string: "...")

    do {
        let undecodedData = try await networkingTools.afRequest(url: url!)
        return decodeMyData(undecodedData)
    } catch {
        print("Failed in afReqest: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhhh so the return goes inside the catch as well! Lots of examples in this answer, thanks you!! Studying it as I write this.